# How to get Emmet to generate a custom JSX attribute without quotes

Tags: reactjs, atom-editor, emmet

I'm trying to remove the quotes generated by Emmet around the `props.onInitiateBattle` value for custom attribute `onClick`.

**My input** (then CTRL + E to expand, similar to tab):
`button.btn[type="button"][onClick={props.onInitiateBattle}]`

**Emmet's output:**
`<button className="btn" type="button" onClick="{props.onInitiateBattle}"></button>`

Notice `props.onInitiateBattle` WITH quotes, which isn't good.

**What I expect** (props... WITHOUT quotes):
`<button className="btn" type="button" onClick={props.onInitiateBattle}></button>`

Wrapping it around double brackets doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

To get single quotes working with JSX you will need to update or create the **syntaxProfiles.json** in **~/emmet** with the syntax profile. I believe that the key is the file extension and the value is the name of the profile that extension will use.

**/* ~/emmet/syntaxProfiles.json */**

/* 'js' will map files with .js extension to use the js profile*/
/* 'jsx' will map files with .jsx extension to also use the js profile*/

```
{
  "js": "js",
  "jsx": "js"
}
```

/* ~/emmet/profiles.json */

/* create or add the 'js' profile */

```
{
  "html": {
    "attr_quotes": "double"
  },
  "js": {
    "attr_quotes": "single",
    "self_closing_tag": true
  }
}
```

[more information](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mcus6p9C5Vg)

Comment: This is not the answear to the question